# How do i get a JSON file out of my SpreadSheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get a `JSON` out my spreadsheet that looks like this([image: SpreadSheet]) and to extract a `JSON` file like this:

```
[{    "module": "ModuleA",
      "Questions" : [{
                      "Question": "xxxx",
                      "Answers" : ["1","2","3"],
                      "right answer" : "2",
            }
    ]
```

This is what i have by now but its not in the coreect hierarchy

```
function doGet(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14-vl75N4mAv9FdZNHIhX_lhtQ-XY17lOvEnLIjiSwDc');
 var result={};

 var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetA')
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();

 var sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetB') 
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();

 result.sheetA = makeObject(sheetA);
 result.sheetB = makeObject(sheetB);

 Logger.log(result.sheetA)
 //return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON. stringify(result))
 //.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

 }

 function makeObject(multiArr) {
   var obj = {};

   var headers = multiArr.shift()
   for(var i = 0; i< headers.length; i++){
   obj[headers[i]]= multiArr.map(function(app){
     return app[i];
   });
   }

   return obj;

 }
```

Comment: Have you seen this http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html ?

Comment: I have now, but i was thinking in a doGet function and mt problem its not with the code to extract de JSON file its about how can i make the hierarchy thats necessary

Comment: If you provide some code of what you've tried, people can help you to come to a working piece of code. Now it seems like you just request someone to write it for you, which is not what SO is for.

Comment: I thought i had posted the code in the begging but i guess i let that slide, tks for the warning.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your Spreadsheet, `Module` and `Right Answer` are used. But in your JSON object, `module` and `right answer` are used as keys. You want to modify the capital letter? 2. In your JSON object, `Questions` is an array. Are there the cases that a `Module` has several questions? If it's so, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including sample situations? I think that such information will also help users think of the solution.

Comment: The capital letter was a mistake, its not relevant. Yes questions are there cause module has multiple questions. i will update the questions with a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What about this solution?

```
function doGet(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14-vl75N4mAv9FdZNHIhX_lhtQ-XY17lOvEnLIjiSwDc');
 var result={};

 var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetA')
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();

 var sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetB') 
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();

result.sheetA = makeObject(sheetA);
result.sheetB = makeObject(sheetB);
Logger.log(makeObject(sheetA))
}  

  function makeObject(multiArr) {
    var obj = [];
  for(var i=1;i<multiArr.length;i++)
  {
    obj.push( {
                      "Question": multiArr[i][1],
                      "Answers" : [multiArr[i][2],multiArr[i][3],multiArr[i][4]],
                      "right answer" : multiArr[i][5],
    }
                    )
  }  
  var myJSON=[{    "module": multiArr[1][0],
                   "Questions" : obj
               }]
  return JSON.stringify(myJSON);
}
```

> You can push into an array your data formatted according to the hierarchy of
>   your choice, populate it within a loop with the contents of each row
>   in your sheet and then `JSON.stringify` it.

This works as above provided you have only one module per sheet. Otherwise, you need to implement an additional function which would detect in which row `ModuleA` ends and `ModuleB` starts.